# NativeScript code sharing project with scss compilation error math.div function undefined

Tags: nativescript, angular11

I am learning native script angular to build mobile and web app. I created a project with the following command

```
ng new -c=@nativescript/schematics sass-project --shared --style=scss
```

my node version is 14.15.2
angular version is 11.0.0
and npm version is 6.14.9

When I execute command

```
tns run android or tns run ios
```

I am getting the following error

```
ERROR in ./app.scss Module build failed (from ../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: Undefined function.
`77 │     $color-brightness: round((red($color) * 299) + (green($color) * 587) + math.div(blue($color) * 114, 1000));
node_modules/@nativescript/theme/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss 77:76  check-contrast()


 node_modules/@nativescript/theme/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss 86:49  alternate()
 node_modules/@nativescript/theme/scss/variables/_index.scss 56:11   @import
 node_modules/@nativescript/theme/scss/core/_index.scss 2:9          @import
 node_modules/@nativescript/theme/core.scss 8:9                      @import
 src/_app-common.scss 1:9                                            @import
src/app.scss 2:9                                                    root stylesheet
 @ ../node_modules/@nativescript/webpack/helpers/load-application-css-angular.js 5:49-65 6:47-63
 @ ./main.tns.ts
```

I tried to clean the project and rebuild it but still facing the same issue. help appreciated.

Comment: What is your tns version?

Comment: tns version is 8.1.5

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I am able to solve this error by adding the following sass dependencies in package.json

```
"sass": "1.34.1",
"sass-loader": "10.1.1",
```

In case, you face any issue to start web then remove node-sass dependency from package.json